# Read data from webpage

Tags: java, html

I am trying to read data from the given web page using Java.

```
public class WebpageReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String line = null, response;
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.co.in/");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn
                .getInputStream()));
        while (rd.readLine() != null) {
            line += rd.readLine();
        }
        System.out.println(line);

    }
}
```

But I'm getting the connection refused exception. What might be correct way to get the date from webpage?

Comment: Can you ping www.google.co.in

Comment: This might help if it is a proxy issue: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0085.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably behind a proxy that doesn't allow you to connect to a web resource through a java application. You can configure a proxy in the java options. In Windows you can do that from the Control Panel.

Comment: This might be the case. Can you please tell me, where i can change this setting in control panel. Im using windows 7

Comment: How to configure this using java option. can u pls tell me

Comment: I used System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true"); in the java code. I included the site name in internet option. It works. Thanks yar.

Comment: it is returning the source of the html page. If i wants to search particular data from the web page, how i can do that

Comment: You are better off asking a new question for this.

Comment: You can provide proxy configuration as JVM arguments, such as `-Dhttp.proxyHost=some.host -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080`. If you use HTTPS, you need also `-Dhttps.proxyHost=.. -Dhttps.proxyPort=..`

Answer (score 1):

You must be having proxy or firewall set. This code works.