# Get filename of file from web directory

Tags: android, file, directory

I'm trying to simply get the filename of a file from an online directory. The directory only has one file in it. The filename is actually the version number. If the filename is "newer" than the file that I already have stored on the android, it will download the file and replace it. I already know how to download the file. I'm not sure if android has some sort of built-in directory lister or if I need to create a PHP file that will display the files, then somehow open and read that in and use that as my path. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to write that PHP script to return the file name.  With that, you can do a straight download from the server.

Comment: I'm thinking that you're right. I hate to sound like a noob, but how in the world do I save the output of the PHP file to a string on android?

Comment: Have the php script serve a "page" that only has the file name.  Read it in through standard Java methods and go to town on it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232535/read-data-from-webpage should get you started with accessing urls in Java.

Comment: That looks pretty easy. I will try it this afternoon. Thanks Haphazard

Comment: That's what we're here for.  If this is the correct answer to your question, remember to select the check-mark beside to to inform others that it worked for you.